# Combining two jQuery plugins and using them as one!

Tags: jquery, plugins, drag-and-drop, zooming, panoramas

I am a newbie to jQuery and stuff. But I have been using some of the plugins for a while. I had

used two very good plugins earlier.

Demo of the plugins:

1. [plugin 1](http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/)
2. [plugin 2](http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery.panorama/)

I was trying to combine the above two plugins and was wanted to see if I could use the

functionalities of both in one image itself. But somehow I am stuck and the panoramic plugin

doesn't seem to work at all.

If anyone of you could please help me in configuring the both into one or direct me in the right

path to use both of them......it would be really helpful and a great relief for me going

forward.

thanks for your time,
manddox

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about the desired outcome of using two plugins together and what you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
Yes I tried the drag-and-drop along with the zoom in-out functionality of the jquery.iviewer plugin for the panoramic view plugin so that the image can be dragged and dropped and zoomed in-and-out and at the same time when we drag the image it goes in loop just like the panoramic view ( starts from the initial position and then loops back to the beginning just like when one clicks the left or right button).

Comment: I tried with the jquery.iviewer plugin initially and then merged the code into it from the panoramic plugin but the panoramic view doesn't seem to work. Also, I noticed that in the panoramic view, a class called advancedpanorma is added which I couldn't figure out how to add this class to the image which has classes added to it dynamically from the jquery.iviewer.js file. Could you please give me more ideas on this?

Comment: Anyone to give me some ideas on how to go about with this please?